# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to initialize TldLocationsCache: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC

Tags: java, jboss

I am using jboss-5.1.0.GA with j2sdk1.4.2_06.

My application is deployed successfully, but I get the error when I browse my app.

http://localhost:8080/esm/

Gives the following error, please help.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to initialize TldLocationsCache: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x47d80677 but got 0x7815789e)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.init(TagLibCache.java:106)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.getLocation(TagLibCache.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldLocation(JspCompilationContext.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1438)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:137)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:300)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)


root cause 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x47d80677 but got 0x7815789e)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.scanJar(TagLibCache.java:343)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.processTldsInFileSystem(TagLibCache.java:268)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.processTldsInFileSystem(TagLibCache.java:261)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.init(TagLibCache.java:101)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.getLocation(TagLibCache.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldLocation(JspCompilationContext.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1438)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:137)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:300)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root cause 
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x47d80677 but got 0x7815789e)
    java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:381)
    java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:148)
    java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:177)
    java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:92)
    java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:70)
    java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(JarInputStream.java:118)
    java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(JarInputStream.java:149)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.scanJar(TagLibCache.java:324)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.processTldsInFileSystem(TagLibCache.java:268)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.processTldsInFileSystem(TagLibCache.java:261)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.init(TagLibCache.java:101)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.TagLibCache.getLocation(TagLibCache.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldLocation(JspCompilationContext.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1438)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:137)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:300)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

---

Thanks for the answe, but even after adding, I get the error.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 54 in the generated java file
>   The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory
>
> An error occurred at line: 177 in the generated java file
>   The method _jspx_meth_bean_005fmessage_005f1(JspTag, PageContext) in the type mainMenu_jsp is not applicable for the arguments (FormTag, PageContext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Jar file in `web-inf/lib` was corrupted.

So got the exception :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to initialize TldLocationsCache: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x47d80677 but got 0x7815789e)
```

To solve this :

Try extracting (**-xvf**) or listing (**-tf**) out all the jars in `web-inf/lib`.

Any jar giving the zip exception while listing or extracting is the corrupted one.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add in jboss5 `default/deployers/jboss.deployer/web.xml`

```xml
<init-param>
   <param-name>engineOptionsClass</param-name>
   <param-value>
      org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jasper.JspServletOptions</param-value>
</init-param>
```

after add

```xml
<init-param> <param-name>engineOptionsClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jasper.JspServletOptions
    </param-value> 
</init-param>
```

Comment: after adding I get this error , Please help                                                              java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jasper.JspServletOptions